# Rubygems on OSX missing

Tags: ruby, rubygems, osx-lion

I feel like a compelte idiot, but I've been wrking on this all day and getting no where.

I've restarted several times trying to get a full install of Ruby on my OSX environment, RVM, Brew, Ruby: and every time I get through to the Ruby install it bottoms out on the rubygems install.

The reason I'm having to start again is that the RVM wouldn't update in Jewelerybox after my first successfull install (used a packaged all-in-one RubyInstaller) so I couldn't manage my gems - a problem caused by the initial Ruby install on the system living in the /usr/local and not under my own directory. To fix this I uninstalled all my Ruby stuff and started again.

All ok until the ruby compiler started gacking on the rubygems install section when installing ruby 2.0.0. Checking out the OSX system files under usr/bin I see that rubygems isn't there either (it should be present by default on OSX). Any ideas? (note that XCode is up to date and has command line tools installed)

Last attempt was:

```
$ rvm get head --autolibs=3 # get the latest RVM and build required libs
$ rvm requirements # just in case, install all other required stuff
$ rvm remove 2.0.0
$ rvm install ruby-2.0.0
```

. . . which fires the following error:

```
[2013-03-19 23:21:50] /Users/matthew.evans/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby
Exception `LoadError' at /Users/matthew.evans/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:1073 - cannot load such file -- rubygems/defaults/operating_system
Exception `LoadError' at /Users/matthew.evans/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:1082 - cannot load such file -- rubygems/defaults/ruby
mkdir -p /Users/matthew.evans/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0
```

...

```
install -c -m 0755 /var/folders/nq/wkj89k854tl0w97n68qdn820pzk_51/T/gem.84634 /Users/matthew.evans/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/gem
rm /var/folders/nq/wkj89k854tl0w97n68qdn820pzk_51/T/gem.84634
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `fu_stream_blksize' for #<Gem::Commands::SetupCommand:0x007ffd0e054818>
Installing RubyGems
Installing gem executable
```

Comment: Try the following: `echo ${LANG:-empty}` then
`export LANG=en_US.utf-8`. After that, try again.

Comment: @AGS Because of a similar issue reported here: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1689 and mirrored here: https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/516

Comment: Confirming that didn't work, and is a different issue.

Comment: Thanks @fmendez, tried that but no joy, lulalala was correct it's not a byte sequence issue. Perhaps there is a way for me to clean down the system and start again?

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same error installing ruby v2 within rvm today.  I was in a user account on Ubuntu who needed to use 'sudo' -- and enter my account password for sudo -- in order to install OS dependencies.

Your question mentions running `rvm requirements` to **install** dependencies.  That seems to be new behavior in rvm, as of v1.19.  It seemed to install a bunch of dependencies just fine.  But then installing ruby bombed.

In earlier rvm versions, typing `rvm requirements` would just **list** the dependencies for rvm and for ruby, as in [Archonic's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15529473/1066093) answer.

I typed `rvm implode` and then started over with:

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s 1.18.21
source /home/deploy/.rvm/scripts/rvm
rvm requirements
```

At that point I could install the libraries/tools that rvm said I needed for rvm and ruby, and then `rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p0` succeeded.

Comment: For reference, the "NEW" libraries missed by `rvm requirements` in rvm 1.19.0 were:

    build-essential dpkg-dev g++ g++-4.6 libapr1 libaprutil1 libdb4.8 libdpkg-perl libneon27-gnutls libstdc++6-4.6-dev libsvn1 subversion

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is where RVM places your dependencies - global vs your user folder. From a book called "Agile development with rails":

> First, you’ll need to make sure you have Xcode 3 or later installed...

```
$ xcodebuild -version
```

> If you have Xcode version 3 installed, you’ll need to install the Git version control system separately. Verify your installation by running the following command:

```
$ git --version
```

> Next, install RVM itself:

```
$ curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

> Exit your command window or Terminal application and open a new one. This causes your .bash_login to be reloaded. Execute the following command, which provides additional installation instructions tailored to your specific operating system:

```
$ rvm requirements
```

> Look for the line that tells you how to install the necessary OS dependencies for Ruby (MRI). Once you complete those instructions, you can proceed to install the Ruby interpreter itself:

```
$ rvm install 2.0.0
```

> The preceding step will take a while as it downloads, configures, and compiles the necessary executables. Once it completes, use that environment, and install rails:

```
$ rvm use 2.0.0
$ gem install rails --version 4.0.0.beta1 --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

> With the exception of the rvm use statement, each of the above instructions need only be done once. The rvm use statement needs to be repeated each time you open a shell window. The use keyword is optional, so you can abbreviate this to rvm 2.0.0. You can also choose to make it the default Ruby interpreter for new terminal sessions with the following command:

```
$ rvm --default 2.0.0
```

> You can verify successful installation using the following command:

```
$ rails -v
```

If you have trouble, try the suggestions listed under the Troubleshooting Your Install heading on the rvm site.

Hope that does it for you!

Comment: I do find I missed some rvm requirements. Once that's sorted, `rvm install 2.0.0` does return similar error still. but running `rvm rubygems latest` after that will install rubygems successfully.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
rvm get head
rvm requirements
rvm install ruby-2.0
```